# Direct sum and direct product of vector spaces

Tags: matrices, category-theory, vector-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The direct sum $\oplus$ versus the cartesian product $\times$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39895/the-direct-sum-oplus-versus-the-cartesian-product-times)

1. (**Definition**) I was wondering how their definitions are different? Are they both
   the cartesian product with the operation of addition being
   componentwise, and the scalar multiplication just distributing over
   all the components?

   How are the following concluded from their definitions:

   > A direct product for a finite index $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ is
   >   identical
   >   to the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n X_i$. The direct sum and
   >   direct
   >   product differ only for infinite indices, where the elements of a
   >   direct sum are zero for all but for a finite number of entries. in
   >   fact, direct sum is a proper subset of direct product.
2. (**With category**) I also wonder why the following is true:

   > Direct sum and direct product are dual in the sense of Category
   >   Theory: the direct sum is the
   >   coproduct, while the direct product is the product.

   If I understand correctly, in category theory, [coproduct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) is characterized by injection
   and [product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28category_theory%29) by projection. To me, both direct sum and direct product
   can be characterized by both injection and projection.
3. (**With matrix**)Are their connection between direct products of vector spaces and of
   matrices (for matrices, as far as I know, their direct product is
   Kronecker product)? Similarly for direct sums of vector spaces and
   of matrices?

   If consider matrices as representation of linear mappings between
   vector spaces, I don't know how they are related.

   if consider a vector as a matrix, the direct product of two vectors
   in the matrix sense is not the same as in vector space sense,
   because the dimensions of the two direct products are not the same.

All quotes are from [Wikipedia](http://Direct_product_of_modules).

Thanks and regards!

Comment: For finitely many factors, the direct sum and the direct products are equal/isomorphic: in fact, they are a "biproduct". It is only when you have infinitely many nontrivial factors that they differ. See [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39895/the-direct-sum-oplus-versus-the-cartesian-product-times). Though the question and answers are about abelian groups, they hold *mutatis mutandis* for vector spaces.

Comment: The first question is answered in the question I've just closed this question as a duplicate of. If you feel that this leaves your other questions unresolved, consider asking them separately. For the second question, look in a category other than abelian groups (such as sets). For the third question, the Kronecker product is the tensor product with respect to a basis, which is neither a categorical product nor a categorical coproduct.

Comment: You can connect direct sums of matrices with direct sums of vector spaces in the following sense: if $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix and $B$ is a $p\times q$ matrix, then $A\oplus B$ is the block diagonal matrix that has upper left block $A$ and bottom right block $q$. Interpreting $A$ as a map $\mathbf{F}^m\to\mathbf{F}^n$ and $B$ as a map $\mathbf{F}^q\to\mathbf{F}^p$, then $A\oplus B$ is the corresponding map $\mathbf{F}^m\oplus\mathbf{F}^q\to\mathbf{F}^n\oplus\mathbb{F}^p$. However, that's a bit of a stretch.