# Difference between $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: notation, integers

Are $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ the same thing or are they different? I keep seeing both notations in a lot of mathematical literature, and I know elements in both are of the form $(a,b)$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39895/the-direct-sum-oplus-versus-the-cartesian-product-times

Comment: They are the same. $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is the direct product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself, $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ is the direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}$ and itself, and direct product and direct sum are the same when the situation involving is finite (they are different if the numbers of elements in the product are infinite).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically,  $\mathbb{Z}^2=\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ whereas $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is the same set along with the associated group operation of pairwise addition inherited from the group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.  We often use the former by abuse of notation.

Comment: There's no abuse of notation here. The category of abelian groups has products and coproducts, they just happen to be canonically isomorphic if the number of factors (here $2$) is finite.

Comment: @Christoph The abuse of notation is associating $\mathbb{Z}$ which is a set with the group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$,  not in the cross product then carrying the group operation

Comment: I see, that is a *very* common "abuse" of notation indeed.

Comment: @Christoph Oh, yes.  I'm just very pedantic :)